# Strange results_Regression_Need some help

Tags: regression

I applied a linear regression between one continuous dependent and one categorical independent. But when I check the residuals vs fitted value the plot is a little bit strange. Also the p value for Durbin[image] Watson test is 0.001. Any Advice? The depended variable is a form of concentration variables and was measure is UL/unit.

Comment: Exactly in what sense do you find this a "little bit strange" and what kind of advice are you seeking?

Comment: @ whuber, the plot of  residuals vs fitted values has a pattern. It means there is a violation of the assumption and also the value of durbinWatsonTest is 0.1 with P-value=0.001. In this case, does it make sense to apply linear regression (Anova)?

Comment: Your independent variable is categorical, apparently with three levels.  So you'll have three different fitted values (one for each level of the categorical variable).  So in the residuals vs. fitted values plot, you'll see residuals plotted at only three different values on the x-axis.  Is that the "pattern" you're talking about?

Comment: Why are you doing a Durbin-Watson test?  Is this a time series?

Comment: @The Laconic, yes, you are right, I made a mistake. Thanks for you help. But is it ok that the durbin Watson test is close to 0.1? And it means that residuals are not independent?

Comment: @ The Laconic, I run Durbin-Watson test on my regression to make sure whether the residuals are independent or not.  I just run a linear regression between the dependent variable and independent variable and then I tried to check the assumptions such as normality of residuals, independency, constant variance and etc. I did not run time series.

Comment: Kindly Be more specific.

Comment: What prompted you to make use of regression ?  What are your variables, sample- size and objectives etc. ?

Comment: Durbin-Watson is not a test for "independence" in general, but for independence of a specific kind (absence of serial correlation).  If you don't have a time series, it's irrelevant; its definition depends on a (regular) ordering of observations in time.